# WinForms Design / Source tabs in VS

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, plugins, ide

Does anybody know of a plugin for VS that makes the IDE have a main tab for a form or control and then secondary tabs for "Design" and "Source" within that specific editor?

Much like the designer of asp.net pages.

I know that the SharpDevelop IDE does this for Winforms.

Check the screenshot if my rambling makes no sense :-)

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the designer. ASP.NET and WPF designers do this already, but the WinForm designed does not. So which designer are you interested in?

Comment: Well, the heading does say WinForms :) and as you say the asp & WPF designers already do this...

Comment: D'oh! I re-read the body and the tags to check... :-) Of course given the state of WinForms development ("use WPF/Silverlight") and the compilation model (no user code in the `form.designer.cs` the designer works against) I wouldn't hold your breath.

Answer (score 0):

[Tabs Studio add-in](http://www.tabsstudio.com) (developed by me) groups **.cs**, **.cs [Design]** and **.Designer.cs** tabs and opens them from the tab context menu.